# How to copy one file to multiple filenames?

Tags: command-line

The command `touch {jan,feb,mar}-{Rep.xls,graph.xls}` creates files I can't open:

feb-graph.xls jan-Rep.xls feb-Rep.xls mar-graph.xls jan-graph.xls mar-Rep.xls

So I created one template file `1.ods`, saved with OO-Calc. Then I tried to copy this file using `cp` again in the same fashion as `cp`:

```
cp 1.ods {jan,feb,mar}{Rep.ods,graph.ods}
```

but that doesnt work:

> cp: target `margraph.ods' is not a directory

How do I copy a single file to multiple files?

Comment: when you give multiple args to `cp` it assumes you want to copy a lot of files to the last one -- which is then expected to be a directory; hence your error.

Comment: So, you want to copy a single file to multiple new files in one command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Combine `cat` (retrieves the contents of a file) with `tee` (writes the content away to the files specified in the arguments):

```
cat 1.ods | tee {jan,feb,mar}-{Rep,graph}.ods >/dev/null
```

Alternative using shell redirection:

```
tee {jan,feb,mar}-{Rep,graph}.ods >/dev/null < 1.ods
```

In both cases, `> /dev/null` is a redirection that discards the duplicated contents (`tee` writes its input to each parameter and standard output).

Comment: +1, nice too! I seem to be biased towards for-loops `;-)`

Comment: @nik: my previous answer included a for loop too, but this one-liner is more clear

Answer (score 4):

How about,

```
for file in {jan,feb,mar}-{Rep.xls,graph.xls}
do
  cp 1.ods $file
done
```

Comment: How this is executable? What execution type or language or filetype is it needs to be?

Comment: It is a bash script. This can be executed in a shell or save it to a .sh file and execute it